# numba njit give my and error on a 2D np.array indexation

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to index a 2D matrix `B` in a njit function with a vector containing the index I want `a`, a slice of matrix `D`
here a minimal example:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit()
def test(N,P,B,D):
    for i in range(N):
        a = D[i,:]
        b =  B[i,a]
        P[:,i] =b

P = np.zeros((5,5))
B = np.random.random((5,5))*100
D = (np.random.random((5,5))*5).astype(np.int32)
print(D)
N = 5
print(P)
test(N,P,B,D)
print(P)
```

I get an error of numba  at the line `b =  B[i,a]`

```
File "dj.py", line 10:
def test(N,P,B,D):
    <source elided>
        a = D[i,:]
        b =  B[i,a]
        ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.
```

I don't understand what AM I doing wrong here.
The code works without the `@nb.njit()` decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numba doesn't support all the same "fancy-indexing" that numpy does - in this case the issue is selecting array elements with the `a` array.

For your particular case, because you know the shape of `b` in advance, you could workaround like this:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def test(N,P,B,D):
    b = np.empty(D.shape[1], dtype=B.dtype)

    for i in range(N):
        a = D[i,:]
        for j in range(a.shape[0]):
            b[j] = B[i, j]
        P[:, i] = b
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to apply swapaxes on B before calling test and to invert indices (`B[i,a]` -> `B[a,i]`). I don't know why this is working, but here is the implementation:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit()
def test(N,P,B,D):
    for i in range(N):
        a = D[i,:]
        b =  B[a,i]
        P[:, i] = b
    
P = np.zeros((5,5))
B = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
D = (np.random.random((5,5))*5).astype(np.int32)
N = 5
test(N,P,np.swapaxes(B, 0, 1), D)
```

By the way, in the answer given by @chrisb, it is not: `b[j] = B[i, j]` but `b[j] = B[i, a[j]]`.